# Parsing File to a New File

Tags: shell, parsing, unix, timestamp

I am parsing a CSV file, and want to write the first token ( which is a timestamp in the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss`) to an output file.  I am using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="inputfile.csv"

while 
    IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
    echo "$f1" > $outfile.txt
done < "$input"
```

The problem is that when you run the script and open the file - it only prints the last line - I would like to print each timestamp, with each one having its own line.  How can I edit my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line overwrite the output file in loop.

```
echo "$f1" > $outfile.txt
```

Use `>>` instead (append instead of overwite):

```
echo "$f1" >> $outfile.txt
```

---

Alternative using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print $1}' inputfile.csv > outfile.txt
```

Comment: @DustinCook, Did you define `outfile`?  Define it. And quote it if possible: `echo "$f1" >> "$outfile.txt"`

Comment: @DustinCook, I added an alternative that use `awk`. Check it out.